# Unable to write input into a file

Tags: java

I have tried many times to read a user input and then write it to a file but I haven't find a solution.  Here is my code...

The main class.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cShell{
    static String Currentpath="C:\\";
    public String Current = Currentpath;
    static HashMap<String, ICommand> myhashData=new HashMap<String, ICommand>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        myhashData.put("ltf", new cITF());
        myhashData.put("nbc", new cNBC());
        myhashData.put("gdb", new cGDB());
        myhashData.put("Tedit", new cTedit());

        String Input = "";
        do{
            System.out.print(Currentpath+"> ");
            //String Input = "";
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            if(scan.hasNext()){
                Input = scan.nextLine().trim();             
            }

            if(Input.equals("exit")){
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if(myhashData.containsKey(Input)){
                ICommand myCommand=myhashData.get(Input);
                myCommand.Execute();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Command");
            }

        }while(!Input.equals("exit"));
    }
}
```

This is the class that do the read and write.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
//import java.lang.System.*;

public class cTedit implements ICommand{

    @Override
    public void Execute() {         
        String filename = "";
        System.out.println("Enter the file name to be edited");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(scan.hasNext()){
            filename = scan.nextLine();
        }

        String line = null;
        try{
            InputStreamReader ISR = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            //FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(ISR);
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(cShell.Currentpath+"\\"+filename);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(ISR);
            System.out.println("Enter text into the file");
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                 fileWriter.write(line);
            }
        bufferedReader.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + filename + "'");
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + filename + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I enter some text as user input, pressing enter doesn't stop me from entering inputs, but when I press Ctrl+z it ran into an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you add your ICommand class file too?

Comment: use `exit` to come out of the loop. `while(!Input.equals("exit"))`

Comment: ICommand is written down..

mport java.io.IOException;


public interface ICommand {
 public void Execute();


}

Comment: @Braj which loop do you.  I used that while loop in the do-while at cShell class...

Comment: Use same logic for `cTedit` also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in `cTedit` class.

`bufferedReader.readLine()` will never return `null` in your case.

Type `exit` to come out of loop.

```
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
         if(line.equals("exit")){
           break;
         }
         fileWriter.write(line);
     }
```

Use `fileWriter.close()` in the end.

Comment: Now the txt is written into the file but as I entered 'exit' to stop taking inputs, the proram run into a infinite loop with the output "Enter file name to be edited" "Unable to open file"...

Comment: What do you mean by this exception `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: Use same logic where you are accepting user inputs in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's not the source of your problem, but I don't think that you need to check the hasnext() condition to read a line :

```
if(scan.hasNext()){
     filename = scan.nextLine();
}
```

just `filename = scan.nextLine();` should be enough.

Comment: I wrote that before just filename = scan.nextLine() but then comes the error related to Null and I found out that the solution for it is to check if it has next line then it will read...

Comment: Have you tried to run in debugging and see if you pass the read the filename operation with your current implementation ? Because that's not normal to have an exception at this point if you don't check the hasnext() condition.

Comment: Yes I have debugged and it passed, so I think it might be another source, If I remove the hasnext(), it will be error as I said..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
 if(Input.equals("exit") || Input.equals("")){
                System.exit(0);
 }
```

instead of

```
 if(Input.equals("exit")){
                System.exit(0);
}
```

In order to close the `fileWriter` after just before exiting add a method `closeFile` as below.

import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.nio.file.Files;
 import java.nio.file.Path;
 //import java.lang.System.*;

public class cTedit implements ICommand{
     private FileWriter fileWriter;
     @Override
     public void Execute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
String filename = "";
System.out.println("Enter the file name to be edited");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
if(scan.hasNext()){
    filename = scan.nextLine();
}

String line = null;

try{

    InputStreamReader ISR = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    //FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(ISR);
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(cShell.Currentpath+"\\"+filename);

      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(ISR);
    System.out.println("Enter text into the file");
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
         fileWriter.write(line);
     }
     bufferedReader.close();
}catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + filename + "'");
}
catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.println("Error reading file '" + filename + "'");
} finally {
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

}

```
 public void closeFile() {
     fileWriter.close();
 }
```

}

and then `callCloseFile` in `cShell` class just before exiting

Comment: What about `fileWriter.close()`? where to put this line. What about statements written below `while` loop?

Comment: The above change needs to be done in cShell class. All else seems fine, you dont need to cose fileWriter.close() in cShell class.

Comment: then where to close the opened file?